# Construct a matrix in Matlab that keeps track of equal elements in each row

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Suppose I have a `IxJ` matrix `A` in Matlab which contains some numbers (possibly, including `Inf`, `-Inf`.

For example, for `I=3` and `J=5`, I could have

```
A=  [0    0      0 Inf -Inf; 
     5    4      0 Inf -Inf;
     Inf -Inf    0 0   0];
```

I want to construct a matrix `B` of size `IxJ`, such that each row `i` starts from `1` and adds a `+1` every time an element of `A(i,:)` changes. In the example above

```
B=  [1 1 1 2 3;  %
     1 2 3 4 5;
     1 2 3 3 3];
```

Could you advise on how to proceed?

Comment: What happens if there are two `inf` together in a row? Should those be considered equal or different?

Comment: They should be considered equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's easy to do with [`diff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) and [`cumsum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html).

#### If consecutive `inf` or `inf` values should count as *different*

```
B = cumsum([true(size(A,1),1) diff(A,[],2)~=0], 2);
```

It works as follows:

- `diff(A,[],2)` takes consecutive differences along each row;
- `~=0` converts nonzero values to `1`;
- `[true(size(A,1),1) ...]` prepends a column of `true` values;
- `cumsum(..., 2)` accumulates the values along each row.

This treats `inf` values as different because `inf-inf`, or `diff([inf inf]`, gives `NaN` rather than `0`.

#### If consecutive `inf` or `-inf` values should respectively count as *equal*

Just replace `diff(...)~=0` by an expression involving only indexing and `~=`:

```
B = cumsum([true(size(A,1),1) A(:,1:end-1)~=A(:,2:end)], 2);
```

This treats `inf` values as equal because `inf==inf` gives `true`, or equivalently `inf~=inf` gives `false`, and similarly for `-inf`.

Comment: Sorry, how can we adjust it to treat consecutive `inf` as the same thing?

Comment: You can replace `inf` with some number that cannot exist in your data, (`realmax` for example?), and then use the same code

Comment: @SardarUsama Good idea. I have used a different approach in my edited answer, which doesn't involve replacing values or creating a copy of the array